# C# mongodb driver - update in sub array not working

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following model (only the improtant type):

```
public class Model
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ModelId;
    public List<Game> Games;
}
public class Game
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId GameId;
    public List<Match> Matches;
}
public class Match
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId MatchId;
    public int[] Votes;
}
```

I have the following query:

```
var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter.And(
                            Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ModelId, modelId),
                            Builders<Model>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Games, t => t.GameId == gameId));

var update = Builders<Model>.Update.Inc(x => x.Games[-1].Matches.First(t => t.MatchId == matchId).Votes[1], 2);
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Model>()
{
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
};
```

Im using `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` and Im able to retreive the data, but no changes are made.
Tried couple of times, still no change.

Answers to Comments:

**Is something being returned?**

Yes, the entire document. moreover, when I use fixed indexes, e.g: games[0].matches[0] everything works fine.

**Did I try to run command in shell?**

No, unfortunartly, so far I haven't tried to work with the shell

Comment: 2 follow ups: (1) does anything get returned when you just run a find with this filter? (2) have you tried running this in shell? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: @CraigWilson answers in edit

Comment: Oh, I think I see the issue... First(t => t.MatchId == matchId) isn't supported in this context. I don't think there is a way to do this in shell syntax. Arguably, we should be throwing an exception here.

Comment: Doesn't "x => x.Games[-1]" throw a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception?

Comment: Craig, so what one should do in case of lookup in nested enumrables? Onosa, no..-1 is the positional operator of mongo. It is replaces with the $ sign

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to use the update.push method for appending an array.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

```
Command command = CreateCommand(commandType,message,source); 
var filter = Builders<Sequence>.Filter.Eq("_id", seqid); 
var update = Builders<Sequence>.Update.Push("Commands", command); 
var result =  collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: Regardless to symantic mistake in your answer. This is not the problem in sub array. The problem was that, alegendly, there are 2 positinal operators when doing sub-sub array update